# SQL - Match String and Update Row, using Excel list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DB Table [List1], 2 columns, Name, Number

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e50b6/3)

I have an excel spreadsheet with 2 columns,names and numbers.
I want to match the Names in Excel to the Names column in SQL and If a match is found insert the relevant number in the second column.

Something tells me I will need to build an array / or csv  and run some Tsql to achieve this.
I originally used the Task> Import data to build the DB Table.

1. Will importing the data again just overwrite the existing data?
2. What is the most efficient way to import the info, but update existing numbers? [EDIT, I have made some progress, read on]
3. I have managed to Create an conditional insert:
   `SET @PersonName = 'Andy
   insert into People (Name, Number)
   select 
   @PersonName
   where not exists (
   select * from People where Name = @PersonName
   );`

How do I pump the name list into the @PersonName variable and loop through the command in SQL?

Update:

I want to update the Datasets based on a dual column First/Last name.
Will this Work?
Update : Yes it worked, final code below.

```
update p
set p.number = s.numbers
from People p
join dbo.[spreadsheet] s on p.Firstname = s.Firstname AND p.lastname = s.lastname
```

Comment: What is the question here? You will need to provide more details about whatever it is you are trying to do before anybody can offer much help.

Comment: I have made the question clearer - above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly and you want to match relatively small amount of data (up to 2k-5k rows) between excel and database table you may perform the next sequence of actions:

1. In SSMS execute: `create table dbo.[spreadsheet] (firstname nvarchar(100), lastname nvarchar(100), numbers int);`
2. In Excel spreadsheet copy to buffer data from `firstname`, `lastname` and `numbers` columns (without headers)
3. In SSMS Object Explorer: Tables->Right click->Refresh
4. Select `dbo.spreadsheet` table->Right click->Edit top 200 rows
5. In the designer select last row->Right click the on row header->Paste
6. And finally execute following update statement (see below)

---

```
update p
set p.number = s.numbers
from People p
join dbo.[spreadsheet] s on s.firstname = p.firstname and s.lastname = p.lastname
```

Comment: This looks great, one more thing, the name column is split into two, "Firstname". "Lastname". How can I deal with that? THe spreadsheet will also be split into first/last name.